# Infinite scroll fetchmore

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

```
const MoreCommentsQuery = gql`
  query MoreComments($cursor: String) {
    moreComments(cursor: $cursor) {
      cursor
      comments {
        author
        text
      }
    }
  }
`;

const CommentsWithData = () => (
  <Query query={CommentsQuery}>
    {({ data: { comments, cursor }, loading, fetchMore }) => (
      <Comments
        entries={comments || []}
        onLoadMore={() =>
          fetchMore({
            // note this is a different query than the one used in the
            // Query component
            query: MoreCommentsQuery,
            variables: { cursor: cursor },
            updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
              const previousEntry = previousResult.entry;
              const newComments = fetchMoreResult.moreComments.comments;
              const newCursor = fetchMoreResult.moreComments.cursor;

              return {
                // By returning `cursor` here, we update the `fetchMore` function
                // to the new cursor.
                cursor: newCursor,
                entry: {
                  // Put the new comments in the front of the list
                  comments: [...newComments, ...previousEntry.comments]
                }
              };
            }
          })
        }
      />
    )}
  </Query>
);
```

This is from the documentation so i cant show the code for the comments query but when executing the CommentsQuery, where does this cursor come from, is it literally just returning the argument we passed in or does the cursor field have to exist on MoreComments Query?

Comment: That would mean i need to implement cursor on the server side?

Comment: Because data: {comments, cursor} if from the database, but i have been told not to implement cursor on server side so how to do it then?

Comment: You've been told __not to **store**__on server side - googling for 'graphql cursor' returns many usefull resources :]